# Making a black hole using charge instead of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, escape-velocity

You can just skip the background portion if you are interested in the real question.

### A bit of Background

I was reading about gravity in my textbook and it mentioned about how in the recent years there's been modification in our knowledge about gravity by introduction of General Relativity by Einstein and how it's prediction led us to finding about the black holes. This was quite an interesting topic for me so I searched and bit more about it on the internet and found that how those cosmic bodies whose escape velocity is greater than $c$ form a black hole. I learned about escape velocity in classical terms and calculated that an earth sized body with mass of about $10^{34}$ would turn into a black hole (though I don't know how it turns out in GR).

### Question

I though since gravitational force has an escape velocity why not electromagnetic ones too! (I think this reasoning might be the cause of the problem?) So I thought what if have a large amount of charge (either positive or negative) I with such a suitable radius that an oppositely charged particle can never escape it (not unless the speed of light changes) i.e., it has something like an escape velocity of $c$ then what would happen?

So here is the question summarized:

- So what if we have large amount of charge of a particular kind and with such a radius that the escape velocity of the opposite charge is greater than $c$ then would it turn into some equivalent of black hole? If not then how's this different from a massive black hole?

It is given that there is no nearby source to neutralize it.

Comment: Even if something like this existed it would not be a "black hole", because light would still be able to escape.

Comment: @Manvendra yeah I thought of it after sometime and hence had already asked about it from sir Ben Cromwell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two important differences between electromagnetism and gravity which are relevant to your question:

- Gravity affects every physical object, and it affects everything in the same way, no matter its mass, energy or anything.
- There are no "negative charges" for gravity: there is only positive mass (and energy).

What this means is that an "electric black hole" doesn't really exist, for a few reasons. First, concentrating a whole bunch of same sign charge in a spot will lead to an enormous electrical repulsion instead of an attraction, so your proposed object couldn't really form in the first place. But assuming that you somehow managed to keep it from blowing up, you have a new problem: the escape velocity depends on the charge of the particle that's trying to escape!

Suppose that your "black hole" is made of positive charge. Then a negative charge will be attracted to it, with bigger charges experiencing more attraction, and hence a smaller "event horizon". But a positive charge would be repelled by this object, and a chargeless particle (like light!) wouldn't even be aware of its existence.

Now compare this with a gravitational black hole. The situation is very simple: there is a certain radius inside which nothing, no matter what it is, can escape. This radius is the same for all objects, because gravity doesn't care what you are made of, it will pull you all the same.

Answer (score 1):

A charged black hole is described by the [Reissner–Nordström metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric). It has two separate adjustable parameters, one for mass and one for charge. Adding charge actually makes the radius of the event horizon smaller, not bigger. If you exceed a certain critical ratio of charge to mass, you no longer get an event horizon at all, and it's not a black hole.

Although your original idea is sensible based on the fact that gravitational and electrical forces are so similar in many ways, the analogy really breaks down because general relativity describes gravity in terms of the structure of spacetime itself, which dictates the possible cause-and-effect relationships. Events inside a black hole's event horizon can't cause events on the outside.

> I searched and bit more about it on the internet and found that how those cosmic bodies whose escape velocity is greater than c form a black hole.

This is OK as a heuristic, but it isn't really the right physics. You can escape from a planet without moving at escape velocity, e.g., by being lifted out with a rope. That isn't true for a black hole.

Comment: I was thinking about this and thought that since photons aren't charged and therefore cannot be attracted by q charged body so how does then a black hole form in this case? Also won't it be just the opposite of a black hole form similar charged particles?

Comment: @safesphere: Your comment seems like a reasonable interpretation of the question and a reasonable answer to it. You might want to post it as an answer.